# Filtering dataframe based on column value

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I want to sort the elements in my data frame and store them in a list. My data contains time points with the corresponding stimulus.

```
    Timepoint  Stimulus
85       75300         5
86       76158         6
87       76661        14
88       76716         7
89       76769         8
90       78722         9
91       79333        10
92       80056         6
93       80559        14
94       80614         7
95       82617         9
96       83228        10
97       83728         6
98       84231        14
99       84286         7
100      86289         9
101      86900        10
102      87440         6
103      87943        14
104      87998         7
105      90001         9
106      90614        10
```

I want to group the time points where the sequence 7,8,9,10 stimulus is present in sequence in one group, and the sequence 7,9,10 in another group. Can anybody please help me out?

I used the Dataframe property of filtering data by value:
`internal = df[(df['Stimulus'] >= 7) & (df['Stimulus'] <= 10)]`

this is only giving me the values as above by removing the other stimulus time points in between

I am coding in Pycharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```py
mask1 = (df["Stimulus"] >= 7) & (df["Stimulus"] <= 10)
mask2 = (mask1 != mask1.shift()).cumsum()

for _, g in df[mask1].groupby(mask2):
    print(g)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
    Timepoint  Stimulus
88      76716         7
89      76769         8
90      78722         9
91      79333        10
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Timepoint  Stimulus
94      80614         7
95      82617         9
96      83228        10
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Timepoint  Stimulus
99       84286         7
100      86289         9
101      86900        10
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Timepoint  Stimulus
104      87998         7
105      90001         9
106      90614        10
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
condition = [7,9,10]
result = [df['Timepoint'][i:i+len(condition)].tolist() for i in range(len(df)) if df['Stimulus'][i:i+len(condition)].tolist() == condition]
```

For your given input it will output the following:

```
result:
[[80614, 82617, 83228], [84286, 86289, 86900], [87998, 90001, 90614]]
```